# TensorFlowLite Run Image classification-model on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

For hours I am trying to get a (I guess) simple trained TensorFlowLite-model to run on Flutter - without success. Maybe somebody can give me a hint - I just want to test, if an image has a cat or a dog on it.

**What I want:**

1. I trained the model with data on Teachable Machine with sample-data from Kaggle
2. I downloaded the `catordog.tflite` with the model, the `labels.txt` (content: `0 Cat; 1 Dog`) and put it with a `cat4001.jpg` in the assets folder

Now I just want that flutter checks the `cat4001.jpg`-image, uses it on the trained model - and prints as debug-info either Cat or Dog.

**What I tried:**

First I tried it with the current, official TFLite-Flutter-package `tflite_flutter 0.10.1`; sadly I couldn't figure it out. I got the dependency, imported the package, and understood it until this line:

```
// Get the labels
var labels = await FileUtil.loadLabels('assets/labels.txt');

final interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/catordog.tflite');
```

But I could not figure out how to continue, and I don't understand the docs ([here](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter)) or anything I found on the web.

Then I tried the "older" packages, `tflite 1.1.2` and `tflite_helper`, but they seem to be outdated. For these I found infos online, even on YouTube, but it's also not really working. I came up with something like this (which still has, after playing with it for hours, many mistakes):

```
  // Get the labels
  var labels = await FileUtil.loadLabels('assets/labels.txt');

  // create ImageProcessor
  ImageProcessor imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
      .add(ResizeOp(224, 224, ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR))
      .build();

  // Read and decode the image from the file
  final File imageFile = File('assets/cat4401.jpg');
  final Uint8List imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();

  // Decode the image using the image package
  final img.Image decodedImage =
      img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes))!;

  // Create a TensorImage object
  final TensorImage tensorImage = TensorImage.loadImage(imageUint8List);

  // Convert the decoded image to a Uint8List
  final Uint8List imageUint8List =
      Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(decodedImage));

  // Create a TensorImage object from a File
  tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

// Convert the bytes to a Uint8List
  Uint8List uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);

  // Anleitung: https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter
  final interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('assets/catordog.tflite');
  //interpreter.allocateTensors();
  print('TensorFlow Lite version: ${tfl.version}');

// For ex: if input tensor shape [1,5] and type is float32
  var input = [
    [1.23, 6.54, 7.81, 3.21, 2.22]
  ];

// if output tensor shape [1,2] and type is float32
  var output = List.filled(1 * 2, 0).reshape([1, 2]);

// inference
  interpreter.run(input, output);
```

So how do I use the Image Classification in a very basic, few line, code? Preferably with the official package of course.
Thanks!